# Cannot assign Variable in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, variable-assignment, cat

I am trying to assign a variable  'email-addr'  to the value (only one) in a file.  The code I have attempted to use throws an error.  I only want to assign the contents of a file, one email address to a variable string.

```
 email-addr=`$(cat ../address)`
```

The contents of ../address is only one line

```
myemail@gmail.com
```

It says:

```
myemail@gmail.com
cat: invalid option -- 'a'
Try `cat --help' for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hyphen isn't allowed as a character in variable names.

Comment: Why are you using both backticks and `$()`? They do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry about the double usage.  I really get mixed up on when to use each.  I did not know that the '-' could not be used in variable names.  That seems to be the crux of the issues, it seems fine now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
my_email=$(cat ../address)
```

Backticks and `$(...)` both execute the command inside and substitute the value. So you're executing the output of `cat ../address` as another command.

And `-` isn't allowed in variable names, I've used `_` instead.

I'm not sure why you're getting the error about an invalid option from `cat`, I don't see anything in what you've posted that would cause that. I suspect it's from something else in your script.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Seems to be fine now.

Comment: Yes, it's OK. Command substitution removes the last newline from the output of the command, since most commands have a trailing newline.

Comment: You could also do `my_email=$(<../address)`

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one email address in the first line of file `../address` and you want to assign to a variable (as already mention, a variable name can't have a hyphen), please consider the *following standard way* of doing:

```
read -r my_email < ../address
```

Your `my_email=$(cat ../address)` is *not* how we would perform this task in bash.